# How Do I Target Only One Button To Change Text When Clicked?

Tags: jquery, button, clipboard, clipboard.js

I'm using Clipboard.js to copy text on a site I'm building. I have everything working well but in the instance where there are multiple buttons, all buttons fire with the success message of text copied.

I have this in my footer:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.4/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn');
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {

    $(".btn span").html("<strong>Copied!</strong> To Clipboard");                 
        });  
                </script>
```

The following code is in the article itself:

```
Example Text <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="Example Text"> <span class="button-text">Copy to Clipboard</span> </button>
```

It works perfectly with one button to copy and paste. Once copied the text of the button changes to "Copied! To Clipboard." However, when there are multiple buttons and one is clicked they are all changed to "Copied! To Clipboard." How do I target only the button the user clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing is caused by a very vague (in your situation) CSS selector to target button text to be updated. This is because `.btn span` returns a collection of all the buttons with class `.btn` and a `<span>` for text inside.

You should benefit from the data available on the event object returned by Clipboard. Here's an example event object structure:

```
{
  "action": "copy",
  "text": "Example Text #1",
  "trigger": <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="Example Text #1">…</button>,
  "clearSelection": function () { [native code] }
}
```

I took the liberty of updating your snippet to use the exact button you are clicking with a focus shift to an input element which is populated with clipboard value:

```js
$(() => {
  const clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn');
  clipboard.on('success', e =>
    $(e.trigger)
    .html("<strong>Copied!</strong> To Clipboard")
    .parent()
    .find('input')
    .val(e.text)
    .focus());
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.4/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<label>
  Example Text #1
  <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="Example Text #1">
    <span class="button-text">Copy to Clipboard</span>
  </button>
  <input placeholder="Ctrl+V here..." />
</label>

<label>
  Example Text #2
  <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="Example Text #2">
    <span class="button-text">Copy to Clipboard</span>
  </button>
  <input placeholder="Ctrl+V here..." />
</label>
```